# Hibernate return query result

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

```
 public Users loginUser(String username,String password)
{
    Users user;
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Users as users where Username ="+ username + " && Password = " +password);
    user = (Users) q.uniqueResult();
    return user;
}
```

I am trying to return the user who is trying to login but it gives me an error from the line which is calling the method above.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /loginlogout.jsp at line 21
```

stack trace:

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Show the full stack trace and the JSP page at line 21 (at least).

Comment: What is in the JSP at line 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try below query:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Users as users where users.Username=:username and users.Password=:password") ;
```

Comment: I dont think that is causing the error because I copied my link in HQL and it worked. 
I think it could be more caused by the following line..

Comment: This is incomplete stacktrace